# Ng-Repeat adds new items to the end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have page with `ng-repeat`. Something like :

```
<div class="full-row" ng-repeat="row in pendingRequests | partition:3 track by $index">
                      <div class="one-third" ng-repeat="request in row track by request.id" ng-mouseenter="EnterRequest(request)" ng-mouseleave="LeaveRequest(request)">
                      ...
```

Every minute there are new request to server for new collection of `pendingRequests`. When after 1 minute server return new collection of `pendingRequests` new item is added to the end of `ng-repeat` block even if this new item is first in collection that is returned from server.

How can I managed to make new/added item be first in `ng-repeat` block?
Similar question that I've found is about `unshift` element to collection. But I have collection which come from server, so I don't add new items manually.

---

2 @Toxantron :

Possible, my problem is because I have 2 `ng-repeat` and only in last repeater I use orderby

```
<div class="full-row" ng-repeat="row in pendingRequests | partition:3 track by $index">
                          <div class="one-third" ng-repeat="request in row | orderBy: '-modificationDate' track by request.id">
```

---

And also there is code of `partition` filter

```
app.filter('partition', function() {
    var cache = {};
    var filter = function(arr, size) {
        if (!arr) { return; }
        var newArr = [];
        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
            newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size < arr.length? i+size : arr.length ));
        }
        var arrString = JSON.stringify(arr);
        var fromCache = cache[arrString+size];
        if (JSON.stringify(fromCache) === JSON.stringify(newArr)) {
            return fromCache;
        }
        cache[arrString+size] = newArr;
        return newArr;
    };
    return filter;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you try `orderBy: '-id'`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.requests = [
    { id: 1, name: "Request 1"},
    { id: 2, name: "Request 2"},
    { id: 3, name: "Request 3"},
    { id: 4, name: "Request 4"},
    { id: 5, name: "Request 5"},
    { id: 6, name: "Request 6"}
  ];
});
app.filter('partition', function() {
    var cache = {};
    var filter = function(arr, size) {
        if (!arr) { return; }
        var newArr = [];
        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
            newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size < arr.length? i+size : arr.length ));
        }
        return newArr;
    };
    return filter;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="requestRow in requests | orderBy: '-id'|partition: 3">
      <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="request in requestRow" >
          {{ request.name }}
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responce. This make sense, but in my case this doesn't work... New item is always in the end

Comment: I will need more code or demo JSON to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did you notice sorting in the sub-groups?

Comment: For sub-groups - yes, but how sub-groups is sorted - it's very strange for me